# ssh port issue:curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '127.0.0.1:ssh'

Tags: ssh

On my windowXP machine,I setup a Winsshd server, and use the command "curl -T test.txt -u hdp:123 sftp://127.0.0.1:22" , it works fine, but when I change the port "22" to "ssh", it failed and prompt "curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '127.0.0.1:ssh'", I donot know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curl` used [RFC3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) for specification of URLs and there is no capacity in that standard for non-numeric port numbers:

> **3.2.3. Port**
>
> The port subcomponent of authority is designated by an optional port number in decimal following the host and delimited from it by a single colon (":") character.
>
> `port = *DIGIT`

It allows for translation of a DNS name, so that you can use `localhost` rather than `127.0.0.1` for example, but not for the port identifier. It would probably be a relatively minor change to allow `curl` to look up services externally (such as in `/etc/services`) but it currently does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the numerical port. 'SSH' is not a port, but port 22 is being used for a ssh connection.